# Check/Solve cross thread operation

Tags: c#, multithreading

There is a StatusProgressBar, which is often accessed from threads. To ensure this, its Text property is as follow:-

```
[Browsable(true)]
    public override string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return prg.Text ;
        }
        set
        {


            prg.Text = value;

        }
    }
```

And the prg.Text = value looks like this

```
public override string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return base.Text;
        }
        set
        {

            Misc.CrossThread(this , delegate
        {

            base.Text = value;
        }, true);
        }

public static void CrossThread(Control control, MethodInvoker d, bool forceSynchronous)
    {

        if (control.InvokeRequired)
        {
            if (forceSynchronous)
            {
                control.Invoke((Action)delegate { CrossThread(control, d, forceSynchronous); });
            }
            else
            {
                control.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate { CrossThread(control, d, forceSynchronous); });
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (control.IsDisposed)
            {
                throw new ObjectDisposedException("Control is already disposed.");
            }

            d();
        }

    }
```

Now the problem is, when its accessed from UI thread (sometimes), the text doesn't change..
ex.

```
if (cbGateway.SelectedIndex == -1) 
    { bp.Text = "Select GATEWAY"; return; }
```

here 'bp' refers to `StatusProgressBar` object.

Now if I put a breakpoint at

```
{ bp.Text = "Select GATEWAY"; return; }
```

and then continue, everything happens as expected, text changes..
Why the text isn't changed first time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you access the progressbar from the UI thread during a long running task, the progressbar will be not refreshed until that long running task is finished.

Comment: @PeterPAD: I've read the question. OP said "Now the problem is, when its accessed from UI thread (sometimes), the text doesn't change.. ex.", so I thought that he is maybe calling the update from a long running task in the UI thread and wanted to give a hint. So I don't understand your downvoting ...

Comment: Thnx for the answer, it almost solved my problem, but there's one thing I want to ask
CrossThread(this , delegate
            {

                base.Text = value;
            }, true);
            }
a warning is issued here, stating "access to Text through base keyword results in unverifiable code"- what is it

Comment: If he IS running a "heavy process" on the UI thread, then he's effectively hogging the UI-thread then NO WONDER the UI's not being updated (sometimes)... the eventing system is overrun... the UI's simply too busy doing the-long-running-stuff-that-should-be-on-a-worker-thread (IMHO).

Comment: @AkshayVats: If that is a different source please ask it in another question together with a code sample. And don't forget to accept one of the answers to this question.

Comment: its this source only, See EDITED

Comment: @AkshayVats: In which code is that property? Are you using a custom progressbar inherit from ProgressBar?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try doing [the following](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents.aspx) in your `CrossThread` method?

```
Application.DoEvents();
```

Comment: Yes, Application.DoEvents(); or bp.Refresh() solves the problem...
But I want to ask about the warning :-
CrossThread(this , delegate { base.Text = value; }, true); } a warning is issued here, stating "access to Text through base keyword results in unverifiable code"
Is there anything I am doing wrong [causing instability to the program], please tell me How you may have written a similar control that is accessed from Threads

Comment: @AkshayVats: Well the warning speaks for itself. You shouldn't access the `Text` property through the `base` instance. The warning is telling you that the compiler can't be sure that there is a `Text` property existing on your object, because `base` isn't indicating what type of object you are working on.